# Hibernate querying results format

Tags: hibernate, format

I have a web service that provides queries functionality using hibernate.
A query can return multiple results - each results contains multiple parameters.

The question is: how should I return the result:

1. Can serialize everything into 1 string nd client will parse it.
2. I know there is a possibility to return Array of strings or Array of complex types.

Which is better for performance - there might be lots of user doing request etc.

If better using the complex types - can give an example of using it - or a link to some info.

Thanks
Yoav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web services generally return results in a platform-independent, but structured way. XML and JSON are two frequent choices.

There are plenty of apis in Java to generate XML and JSON. Google for them. I like using JAXB for XML. Some APIs take JAXB-annotated objects and serialize them into JSON instead of XML.

Comment: it is using soap - but what is better for performance - a string or a complex type

Comment: Make it usable and correct before thinking about making it fast. Use a complex type, which will be directly usable by your clients, rather than forcing them to implement a complex parsing algorithm. web services are slow because of the network, not because of the transmitted data.